# Joining two files from the command line in a Linux environment

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm looking for a solution for the following simple problem. I have two files, `fileA` and `fileB`. Each file contains only one word per line, and they contain exactly the same number of lines.

I would like to create a new file called `fileAB`, where the i-th line contains the i-th line of `fileA`, a Tab separator character, and then the i-th line of `fileB`. I know how to do it in Python or other scripting languages, but it would be nice to have a bash one-liner for that.

Is it possible to do this in bash or any other Unix shell, using the tools that are usually available on the command line (e.g., `sed`, `awk` and such)?

Comment: Ignacio's answer is of course excellent, but it's worth mentioning that python *is* availbable on the command line and is in principle no less of a "one liner" than sed or paste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `paste`.

```
paste fileA fileB > fileAB
```

Comment: Yay, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`parallel --xapply -j1 -a file_1 -a file_2 echo {} > file_12`

or an alternative style

`parallel --xapply -k echo :::: file_1 :::: file2 > file_12`

The shorter file will wrap its lines to match the length of the longer file.(if you want this behavior)